# First time using the PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, soap

I've started writing some code to use SOAP within PHP.

Managed to get my code to login and authenticate, which is a start!

I initially had the following code :

```
$params = array(
  "Parcels" => 1,
  "RecipientAddress" => "123 Any Street, Any Town, Anywhere",
  "RecipientName" => "Joe Bloggs",
  "CollectionDate" => "2019-11-11",
);

// Invoke WS method (Function1) with the request params 
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetAvailableServices", array($params));

// Print WS response
var_dump($response);
```

Which returned the following message :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Missing Recipient Address Element 'RecipientName' in /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php(17): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetAvailableSer...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php on line 17
```

I've tried changing the code to :

```
$params = array(
  "Parcels" => 1,
  "RecipientAddress" => array(
  "RecipientName" => "Joe Bloggs",
),
  "CollectionDate" => "2019-11-11",
);

// Invoke WS method (Function1) with the request params 
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetAvailableServices", array($params));

// Print WS response
var_dump($response);
```

Which returned this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'RecipientAddress' property in /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php(18): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetAvailableSer...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/thisone/public_html/despatchbayservices.php on line 18
```

I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid but I just cant see it - any help massively appreciated!

Comment: The first snippet but instead of wrapping params in an array you do:

`$response = $client->__soapCall("GetAvailableServices", $params);`

Comment: Does the web service you're using provide a WSDL? That should show you the correct formats for the requests it supports.

Comment: The WSDL is at https://api.despatchbay.com/soap/v15/shipping?wsdl but i have to admit i'm still none the wiser!

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it - thanks to Don't Panic for pointing me toward the WDSL.

For reference the correct/working code is :

```
$params = array(

"Parcels" => array(
  "ParcelType" => array(
    "Weight" => 5,
    "Length" => 5,
    "Width" => 5,
    "Height"=> 5,
  )
 ),
"RecipientAddress" => array(
  "RecipientName" => "Joe Bloggs",
  "RecipientAddress" => array(
      "CompanyName" => "My Company",
      "Street" => "123 Any Street",
      "Locality" => "Anywhere",
      "TownCity" => "Any Town",
      "County" => "Somewhere",
      "PostalCode" => "TS23 4EA",
      "CountryCode" => "GB",
)
),
  "CollectionDate" => "2019-11-11",
);

// Invoke WS method (Function1) with the request params 
$response = $client->__soapCall("GetAvailableServices", array($params));
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply yesterday. When more than two people have commented it doesn't notify you when someone replies unless they @ you. Glad you got it figured out! I wouldn't have guessed RecipientAddress needed a RecipientAddress in it. :-) By the way, if you construct your soap client with the WSDL, I think you can call its methods directly, like `$client->GetAvailableServices` if I remember correctly.